# jquery .each() won't work with div identifier before input[type=checkbox] on IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, each

I have such piece of code. I have 4 sets of checkboxes on a form and each set has to go through this function separately. ID variable is an id of a given div placed around each set

```
 $('#'+id+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
         (...)
 });
```

Works fine on chrome, firefox and IE9. Doesn't work on IE7/8.

What works on IE7/8 tho is this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
         (...)
 });
```

So it works without div identifier. I still need to be able to tell IE7/8 which set of checkboxes I want it to go through. How should I accommodate that div identifier so it works on older IEs?

Comment: Your code as such works fine in IE 7 http://jsfiddle.net/skram/33wkH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If checkboxes are organized in groups or sets, the way I usually do this is adding an array name to the checkbox group and use that in jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="groupone[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="groupone[]"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="grouptwo[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="grouptwo[]"/>
```

And in jQuery:

```
$('input[name="groupone[]"]').filter(':checked')
```

Comment: all three solutions described work, but I ended up using this one. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.find` and `.filter` like below,

```
$('#'+id).find('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').each(function () {
 //..
```

you can use `:checkbox` instead of long `input[type=checkbox]`

```
$('#'+id).find(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one element with that ID in your page, IE might be choking on it. But the pattern I usually use for what you're doing is more like this:

```
$('#' + id)
  .find('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
  .each(function() { /...
```

You can use `.find(':checkbox:checked')` in place of the second line, but you should get better performance with the above code. `[type=checkbox]` can use [a native method in modern browsers that improves efficiency.](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) Also, `.find(':checkbox')` apparently makes jQuery check every element in the div to see if it matches `:checkbox`, even elements that aren't inputs (so they can't possibly be checkboxes). This may have been solved in the latest versions of jQuery, but not that I know of.